# CGI table with perl

Tags: html, forms, perl, cgi

I am trying to build a login form with `CGI`, using `perl`.

```
sub show_login_form{
return div ({-id =>'loginFormDiv'}),
    start_form, "\n",
    CGI->start_table, "\n",     
    CGI->end_table, "\n",   
    end_form, "\n",
    div, "\n";
}
```

I was wondering why I don't need to add `CGI->` before `start_form` but if I don't include it before `start_table` and `end_table`, `"start_table"` and `"end_table"` are printed as `strings`?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please don't do that. The HTML generation functions in CGI were always a bad idea (even [the documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI#HTML-Generation-functions-should-no-longer-be-used) agrees). Use a templating system instead.

Comment: What Dave says. Additionally there are far better alternatives these days than CGI for writing web apps/scripts. See the CGI documentation itself which lists some other options, together with examples https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Alternatives

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Why can I use you some subroutines?

Because you are likely importing them using the following use statement:

```
use CGI qw(:standard);
```

As documented in [CGI - Using the function oriented interface](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI#Using-the-function-oriented-interface), this will import "standard" features, 'html2', 'html3', 'html4', 'ssl', 'form' and 'cgi'.

But that does not include the table methods.

To get them too, you can modify your use statement to the following:

```
use CGI qw(:standard *table);
```

#### Why does removing CGI-> print start_table as a string?

Because you unwisely do not have [`use strict`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) turned on.

If you had, you would've gotten the following error:

```
Bareword "start_table" not allowed while "strict subs"
```

Comment: It's perhaps also worth adding "and because you forgot to `use strict`".